# Ruby: Splitting string on last number character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following method in my Ruby model:

Old:

```
def to_s
    numbers = self.title.scan(/\d+/) if self.title.scan(/\d+/)
    return numbers.join.insert(0, "#{self.title.chop} ") if numbers

    "#{self.title.titlecase}"
  end
```

New:

```
def to_s
    numbers = self.title.scan(/\d+/)
    return numbers.join.insert(0, "#{self.title.sub(/\d+/, '')} ") if numbers.any?

    self.title.titlecase
  end
```

A `title` can be like so: Level1 or TrackStar

So TrackStar should become Track Star and Level1 should be come Level 1, which is why I am doing the scan for numbers to begin with

I am trying to display it like Level 1. The above works, I was just curious to know if there was a more eloquent solution

Comment: Is the digit is always the last character? Is there always a digit there?

Comment: @texasbruce - yes, the last character is always the last digit

Comment: `"#{self.title.titlecase}"` has quotes around it for no reason. This should probably be `self.title.titlecase`, or if you're worried about creating a duplicate string, then `self.title.titlecase.dup`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def to_s
  self.title.split(/(?=[0-9])/, 2).join(" ")
end
```

The second argument to `split` is to make sure a title like "Level10" doesn't get transformed into "Level 1 0".

**Edit** - to add spaces between words as well, I'd use `gsub`:

```
def to_s
  self.title.gsub(/([a-z])([A-Z])/, '\1 \2').split(/(?=\d)/, 2).join(" ")
end
```

Be sure to use single-quotes in the second argument to `gsub`.

Comment: dennis' solution actually returns `"Level1 1"` for an input of `"Level10"` ;-)

Comment: Why `[0-9]` instead of `\d`?

Comment: Simply for consistency with the question (as originally posted).

Comment: Didn't know about the second argument to split, also: great answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
'Level1'.split(/(\d+)/).join(' ')
#=> "Level 1"
```

Comment: As per @WallyAltman's point - this won't work properly if the number has more than one digit.

Comment: You're right, modified the regex to `\d+` instead of `\d`. Althoug it still does not match only the _last_ occurence.